# Sum of multiple products

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following table

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 31 | 47 | 58 |
| 13 | 21 | 33 | 42 | 55 |
| 14 | 27 | 32 | 44 | 55 |
| 17 | 29 | 35 | 45 | 56 |
| 18 | 26 | 34 | 43 | 53 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| C | 50288 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 2520 | 14040 | 33728 | 88924 | 169070 |

For each column I calculate the product of the rows 1, 3, and 5. The value in cell A7 tells me until which column I then sum of all the products into one single value.

With the values in row 9 that are the products of each respective column, I can then use `=SUM(INDIRECT("A9:"&A7&"9"))` to get the correct sum, which is 50288 in this example. However, I'd like to get to that value without the need of row 9. How can I achieve that?

Comment: SUMPRODUCT with your arrays going across rows, & use INDIRECT like you already have to set your end column dynamically

Comment: I thought that SUMPRODUCT is the thing to use, but I couldn't figure out how to get it working. It would have got it working if the cells I'm using are adjacent, but since they're not, I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Ok, now that I read your answer again, I figured it out! Didn't know that i can use the sumproduct accross rows as well. Thanks!